# git repository structure with multiple modules

Tags: git, repository, git-submodules

I have the following situation:

1. Have 4-5 different software modules part of a bigger software project.
2. All of them are set as separate git repos.
3. When i commit a feature, usually it spans more than a single module - thus making e.g. 2 or 3 commits for each module.

Give me ideas for multiple modules part of a bigger project. Do you prefer using git submodules, and if yes, in what way? Or do you use a master folder for the project, e.g.:

Software_Project
   Module_1
   Module_2
   Module_3
   Module_4

Any ideas for an appropriate git repo structure are welcome.

Comment: +1 A very nicely written question!

Comment: *“When i commit a feature, usually it spans more than a single module”* – That sounds wrong to me. Usually submodules are meant to be independent from the parent repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are saying that you commit features that usually span over several modules, I'd put everything in the same git repository, unless it's truly an orthogonal module and completely independent from the rest of the project, where instead a submodule might be appropriate. You will be happy to have the possibility to commit features the way git was supposed be used. Multiple commits in several git repositories? Nah, I'd rather have the code closer together. Well, it's a trade off like everything else.

Comment: I think I am going to move in the direction of a single folder with the modules inside. Similar to what Assembla git repo structure looks like. Code should be closer together, one commit per feature, not making 4 commits for the same feature in the different modules.

Comment: That's the way to go and it helps with confidence and makes it so much easier to revert changes. Imagine trying to do that manually on all repos. Back to CVS time! *shudder* :D

Answer (score 1):

Google developed a script for Android development called [Repo](http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html) (apparently [the website has moved](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo)) that makes git usage easier. Its main purpose is easier management of multiple repositories.

Comment: I'll check it although I am not sure this is what I need.